# Linqpad keyboard-shortcuts for cycling through the result panels

Tags: linqpad, linqpad7

I am looking for the keyboard-shortcuts for cycling through the result panels. I have plenty of queries that dump intermediate results into different datagrids. I would like to have a keyboard shortcut for cycling though the various result windows.

Alt+up/down scrolls nicely up and down though the content of the focussed result panel. I hoped one of alt+[page-up/down | home/end | left/right] would cycle me through the different result panels. But that does not seem to be the case. The help file states these are mapped to 'scroll output panels', so I guess this means scrolling within the content of the currently focussed panel only.

Is there some other way to cycle through the result panels via keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQPad's keyboard shortcuts are listed in Help | Keyboard Shortcuts. To move between output panels, hold down Shift+Ctrl+Alt and use the Left/Right keys.

Comment: Selective attention at it's finest. It was perfectly stated in the helpfile, literally just 1 line above the (yellow) line I quoted. Thanks for the prompt answer Joseph. And for the great tool Linqpad is, as well.